# Create new variable

Tags: r, variables, analysis

I have a `data.frame` which contains 713 rows and one of it's columns `itemcode` has 228 unique codes. My question is, how to create a choice selection for all the IDs?

```
nrow(test.1)
[1] 713

length(unique(test.1$itemcode))
[1] 228

head(test.1)
       itemcode ID
2    1180158001  1
225  1180149701  2
264  1180074301  3
522  1180177701  4
732  1180197201  5
1182 1170015601  6
```

Here is my trial code:

```
test$ID <- 1:nrow(test)
for (i in unique(test$itemcode)) 
    for (j in 1:length(unique(test$itemcode))) 
        test$choice[test$itemcode == i] <- j
```

My Desired output would be something like this

> ```
>       itemcode  ID choice  
> 2    1180158001  1 1   
> 225  1180149701  2 2  
> 264  1180074301  3 3   
> 522  1180177701  4 4   
> 732  1180197201  5 5   
> 1182 1170015601  6 6   
> 523  1180177701  7 4
> ```
>
> This works. But if test.1 is a subset of test? This code would return the underlaying values from test.

```
test$choice <- as.integer( as.factor( test$itemcode ) )
```

Comment: I've edited the question for formatting and rewrote the lines. But I still think the title and body needs improvement.

Comment: I second @Arun - it's really hard to tell what you are actually after. Please add some desired output, it would really help!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the output data (+1). I've edited my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you want `factor`...

```
test$choice <- as.integer( as.factor( test$itemcode ) )
```

This will turn each unique `itemcode`into a integer coded variable. The `as.integer` will show you what the underlying values are. If you want them ordered as they appear in the `data.frame` you need to specify the `levels` of your `factor` variable and you can do this using `factor` rather than `as.factor`.

```
#  Turn them into an integer code - ordering is sorted on value of itemcode
test$choice <- as.integer( as.factor( test$itemcode ) )

# Same, but specify ordering as the values appear in the dataframe
test$choice2 <- as.integer( factor( test$itemcode , levels = test$itemcode[ ! duplicated( test$itemcode ) ] ) )

       itemcode ID choice choice2
2    1180158001  1      4       1
225  1180149701  2      3       2
264  1180074301  3      2       3
522  1180177701  4      5       4
732  1180197201  5      6       5
1182 1170015601  6      1       6
523  1180177701  7      5       4
```